# Convert part of the values in a column to numeric and keep characters to otehrs

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column V1 with numbers and characters but all are imported as characters like that :

```
 unique(gtf_file$V1)
 [1] "1"  "16" "X"  "17" "12" "15" "14" "8"  "4"  "3"  "5"  "11" "6"  "22" "9"  "10" "20" "19" "7"  "2"  "18" "13"
[23] "21" "Y"
```

How can i transform as.numeric only the number values of the column and keep the X and Y. If i do simply `as.numeric(gtf_file$V1)` it converst the X and Y to NAs.

Comment: I guess you can't. A column can only have one type. You cas use mixed types in a list though...

Comment: A potential workaround is to relabel "X" as chromosome 23, and "Y" as 24, but without more details it's hard to help, sorry.

Comment: this will be used further to join with another column from another file with chr numbers so either i have to rename both to 23-24 or somehow keep the X and Y

Comment: @user3683485 you can use the ```ifelse``` function in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gtf_file$V1 <- ifelse(grepl("^\\d+$", gtf_file$V1), as.numeric(gtf_file$V1), gtf_file$V1)
```

`grepl("^\\d+$", gtf_file$V1)` checks if each element in column V1 is composed of only digits. If it is, `as.numeric(gtf_file$V1)` converts that element to numeric. Otherwise, it keeps the original value as it is.